# Load new data form server on scrolling | Pagination | Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, pagination, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement pagination on my flutter app. The task is to load/fetch new data on scrolling. I'm able to fetch data from the server on every scroll but the thing is every time the same data is fetched.

Here's my code for your review:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchEvents(String accessToken,int vehicleId,) async {
    String url = '${AppConstants.baseUrl}v2/event/paginated?size=10&offset=${offset++}&eventsId=${widget.eventsId}';

    final response = await get(
      Uri.parse('$url'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "bearer $accessToken",
      },
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    fetchedEvents = [...responseBody['eventResponses']];
    for (var event in fetchedEvents) {
      setState(() {
        events.add(event);
      });
    }
    return responseBody;
  }
```

On every scroll the offset gets updated yet returns the same data.

But on Postman, if I change the offset new set of data gets fetched. Where am I going wrong?

Here's my initState()'s code:

```
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadMoreData(); //initial data is fetched
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.position.pixels == _controller.position.maxScrollExtent) { //data fetched on scroll
        loadMoreData();
      }
    });
  }
```

Here's laodMoreData():

```
loadMoreData() {
    fetchEvents(widget.accessToken, widget.eventId);
  }
```

Please help me overcome this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use controller for this
you can  add  1 to the itemCount to load next Page

```
   ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length+1,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if(i<list.length)
           {
           return listItem()
            }
        else{
          loadMoreData()//this function will be called with the last listitem 
          return Loader()  //loader for pagination
            }
        },
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I'll try this and update you.